# Merge Allocated Space with Unallocated space in Gparted

Tags: linux-mint, partition, gparted

I have a dual booted machine (Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon and Windows 10) and am looking to allocate space from Windows to Linux. I have already removed space from my C:\ and D:\ Drive without any issues, but I am having trouble extending my Linux Partitions. My Allocated space is BELOW the unallocated space. Here is a screenshot(It is as accurate as I could make it):[image: GPARTED Drives]

I would like to add the Unallocated Space above the "Linux Root" partition to the partition named "Linux Home." I would also like to add the unallocated space at the very bottom to "Linux Root."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, backup your data.

Boot Linux from a Live USB ([GParted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) or your Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon Live USB) and start GParted.

Instead of assigning the unallocated space at the bottom to "Linux Root", it's easier to use a part (~14GB?) of the unallocated space at the top.

1. Resize/move `/dev/sda5` "Linux Root", grow the partition to the wanted size, i.e. if you enlarge the partition by 14 GiB, move the partition to the left side so you'll end up with about 50 GiB after "Linux Root":

   ```
   ...
   /dev/sda3 Basic data partition
   /dev/sda5 Linux Root           27.94 + 14 GiB
   unallocated                    ~50 GiB
   /dev/sda6 Linux Swap
   /dev/sda7 Linux Home
   /dev/sda4 Basic data partition
   unallocated                    14.65 GiB
   ```
2. Move `/dev/sda6` "Linux Swap" to the left:

   ```
   ...
   /dev/sda3 Basic data partition
   /dev/sda5 Linux Root           27.94 + 14 GiB
   /dev/sda6 Linux Swap
   unallocated                    ~50 GiB
   /dev/sda7 Linux Home
   /dev/sda4 Basic data partition
   unallocated                    14.65 GiB
   ```
3. Move `/dev/sda4` "Basic data partition" to the right:

   ```
   ...
   /dev/sda3 Basic data partition
   /dev/sda5 Linux Root           27.94 + 14 GiB
   /dev/sda6 Linux Swap
   unallocated                    ~50 GiB
   /dev/sda7 Linux Home
   unallocated                    14.65 GiB
   /dev/sda4 Basic data partition
   ```
4. Resize `/dev/sda7` "Linux Home" to take up the unallocated space before and after the partition.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I move "unallocated" under /dev/sda5? Or does it just work when using a live USB?

Comment: Yes, it just works with a Live USB. Your partition is currently locked (the key symbol) because it's in use.

Comment: I see. So it will work with live USB because the drive is in use when you do it in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

This will require you moving partitions around, which can get dangerous; hopefully you have backups. LVM would've made it easier; this is why Fedora makes that the default.

1. Move partitions around to have the unallocated spaces *after* the partitions you want extended.
2. Extend the partitions
3. Extend the underlying file systems